# Am having issues in grouping and rank in php

Tags: php, sql

Am issues with grouping and rank in php i don;t know if my entire code is wrong but have been able to group it and rank but the ranking is not correct
Here is my code

```
SELECT g1.regnumber, g1.subject_id , g1.score , COUNT(*) AS rank
FROM tbl_result AS g1 JOIN
     tbl_result AS g2
     ON (g2.score, g2.regnumber) >= (g1.score, g1.regnumber) AND
        g1.subject_id = g2.subject_id
 WHERE g2.subject_id='11'
 GROUP BY g1.regnumber, g1.subject_id , g1.score
 ORDER BY g1.subject_id , rank
```

Here is the result

```
regnumber   subject_id   score   Rank   
0217            11         89      1
0200            11         78      2
2021            11         50      3
7737            11         200     4
0917            11         100     5
```

Which is not correct

Don't mind my code, all i need is a sql code that can group and rank also using where clause.
Thanks.

Comment: I think you are storing the scores as strings rather than numbers.  Fix your data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem would appear to be storing the score as a string rather than a number.  You can fix the query.  But I would go to the root cause and fix the problem by doing:

```
alter table modify column score int;
```

I do think the query is a bit cumbersome.  I would be more inclined to write it using a correlated subquery or using variables.  The latter is pretty simple:

```
SELECT tr.regnumber, tr.subject_id, tr.score,
       (@rn := @rn + 1) as rank
FROM (SELECT tr.*,
      FROM tbl_result tr
      WHERE g1.adnumber = 'ctydemo' AND g2.subject_id = 11
      ORDER BY tr.score DESC, tr.regnumber DESC
     ) tr CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @rn := 0) params
ORDER BY tr.subject_id, rank;
```

Note:  This assumes that the type of `score` is fixed.  It is easy enough to adjust the query by doing:

```
ORDER BY (tr.score + 0) DESC, tr.regnumber DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

seems that your score is a string

in this case if you don't want change the struct of your table  you can try cast your score column from string to int

```
  SELECT g1.regnumber, g1.subject_id , g1.score , COUNT(*) AS rank
  FROM tbl_result AS g1 JOIN
       tbl_result AS g2
       ON (cast(g2.score as integer), g2.regnumber) >= (cast(g1.score as integer), g1.regnumber) AND
          g1.subject_id = g2.subject_id
   WHERE g2.subject_id='11'
   GROUP BY g1.regnumber, g1.subject_id , g1.score
   ORDER BY g1.subject_id , rank
```